# ClamTK Scan Result Location CentOS 7

Tags: centos, security, logs, clamav

I've setup ClamTK on my CentOS 7.9 PC and I wanted to know where the on demand scan results are stored? I couldn't find any references on the developer website nor the Linux `man` pages.

Would anyone happen to know where they are stored? Thanks in advance.

[image: ClamTK GUI]

Comment: Example from a  Google search https://answers.launchpad.net/clamtk/+question/246120    → History logs are under ~/.clamtk/history

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems like I posted my findings at the same time you provided your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the location of the scan results in the end after further hunting.

The location of the scan history shown in the ClamTK GUI is stored in the users `home` directory, specifically in:

```
/home/<username>/.clamtk/history/<date>.log
```

I hope this information may be of use to other users.